# python sort list of tuples on custom sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort a list of tuples, on the first element of the tuple, using a custom pre-defined list as the desired order.
So I have the list as

```
my_list=(['chr1',12],['chrX',32],['chr2',1],['chr1',79],['chr2',6])
```

and the predefined list on the first element is

```
custom_list=['chr1','chr2','chrX']
```

I want the output to be

```
(['chr1',12],['chr1',79],['chr2',1],['chr2',6],['chrX',32])
```

(For now, sorting on the second element is not needed.)
I can't figure out how to do this . Can anyone help please?

Comment: You have there a tuple of lists, not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `list.index()` function to turn position in the `custom_list` into a sort key:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (custom_list.index(x[0]), x[1]))
```

You may want to turn your `custom_list` into a dictionary however, for faster mapping:

```
custom_list_indices = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(custom_list)}
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (custom_list_indices.get(x[0]), x[1]))
```

Dictionary lookups take constant time, `list.index()` time is directly proportional to the length of the list.

Another advantage is that with a dictionary, you can return a default value for entries not found in the dictionary (`None` in this example); `list.index()` will raise a `ValueError` exception instead.

Demo:

```
>>> my_list=(['chr1',12],['chrX',32],['chr2',1],['chr1',79],['chr2',6])
>>> custom_list=['chr1','chr2','chrX']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (custom_list.index(x[0]), x[1]))
[['chr1', 12], ['chr1', 79], ['chr2', 1], ['chr2', 6], ['chrX', 32]]
>>> custom_list_indices = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(custom_list)}
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (custom_list_indices.get(x[0]), x[1]))
[['chr1', 12], ['chr1', 79], ['chr2', 1], ['chr2', 6], ['chrX', 32]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. How about the case where instead of a list of tuples, I have a list of objects? And I want to sort on a field in that object on the custom_list array?